# How can I make an arrow's shaft more visible?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, geometry, vector-calculus, homework

```
{Graphics[{Arrowheads[.1], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}], 
Graphics[{Arrowheads[.1], 
Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}]]}]}
```

say I have the above code. Can I make the arrows smaller? In other words can I make it smaller relative to the other objects that might be plotted in the same graphics?

Comment: Change x in Arrowheads[x] to change the size.

Comment: @iav I tried modifying this between a wide range and it didn't help. I think that only works for the arrowheads, but not the shaft. The head gets smaller, but the shaft is not visible. Perhaps I should be looking for something to make the shafts wider and longer while making the head smaller

Comment: The shaft is controlled by `Thickness`.

Comment: Actually, `AbsoluteThickness` is better than `Thickness` for correcting rendering visibility problems because it adjusts lines and curves in printer's points and thus independent of object scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Arrowheads[a], 
           Thickness[b], 
           Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}],
 {a, 0, 1},
 {b, 0.01, 0.3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
GraphicsColumn[
  Graphics[
    {AbsoluteThickness[#],
     {Arrowheads[.1], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]},
     {Arrowheads[.1], Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}]]}}] & /@ 
  Range[5]]
```

[image: arrows]